# Display issues in Ubuntu Linux: monitor keep turning on & off during sleep and primary display run at lower refresh rate

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, sleep, nvidia-graphics-card, refresh-rate

Just moved out from Windows 11 to Ubuntu 22.04 for almost 2 weeks and noticed that when the computer is in sleep mode (screen blank power saving option on Ubuntu), monitor goes to a black screen for a moment, shows monitor message for no display, turned off for a moment and then shows message that monitor receive 1920x1080 display from display port. This keeps happening on both of my monitor as I use a dual monitor setup.

I'm guessing the problem is from nvidia driver for linux since both monitor is connected to my Gtx 1650 graphics card and I also have some other display issues such as my 165hz main monitor seems to run at 60hz when secondary display is connected but mouse cursor and even games like Dota 2 seems to run at full 165hz even on windowed mode. Tried Forced Full Composition Pipeline from Nvidia Settings and doesn't seem to help at all.

Any help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.